# opencart how to addEvent Journal3?

Tags: php, opencart, journal

work fine in default opencart checkout
example..

1. $this->model_setting_event->addEvent('custom_name', 'catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/payment_method/after', 'event_function');
2. $this->model_setting_event->addEvent('custom_name', 'catalog/controller/checkout/payment_method/save/after',
   'event_function');
3. $this->model_setting_event->addEvent('custom_name', 'catalog/model/checkout/order/addOrder/before', 'event_function');

how can i make it work with journal3 one checkout page?

opencart 3.0.2.0

Comment: Do you mean you want to trigger an event when customer successfully checkout with Journal 3 checkout page?

Comment: @SternChen I want to show my A.twig with Journal 3 checkout page.And I have tried 
$this->model_setting_event->addEvent('custom_name', '/catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/checkout/payment_method/after', 'event_function');

Comment: Hi, can you clarify your goal again? I am not understand your requirement whether you are trying to modify the view of checkout page or you want to trigger an event?

Comment: Hi,sorry for my poor English.I want to do both. modify the view of checkout page through trigger an event

Comment: I see, may I know which OpenCart version you using?

Comment: opencart 3.0.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **2 approaches**, you can choose **either one** to implement based on which approach is more applicable to your situation:

1. Replace the view file before rendering the output
2. Modify the html through the output

> I assuming you already know how to register an event, following
> example just demonstrate how to implement the approach. Leave me a
> comment to let me know if you not sure how to register an event.

**1. Replace the view file before rendering the output**

Create an event script: `catalog/controller/event/my_event.php`

```
/* before */
public function beforeLoadCheckoutView(&$route, &$args) {
    /*
        if the view route is 'journal3/checkout/checkout',
        aka: 'catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/journal3/checkout/checkout.twig'
    */
    if ($route == 'journal3/checkout/checkout') {
        /*
            replace the view file 'journal3/checkout/checkout' with your own view file
            aka: 'catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/journal3/checkout/my_checkout_page.twig'
        */
        $route = str_replace('journal3/checkout/checkout', 'journal3/checkout/my_checkout_page', $route);
    }
}
```

Create your own checkout page view: `catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/journal3/checkout/my_checkout_page.twig`

```
<div>
    I have replace the original view with this!
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

**2. Modify the html through the output**

Create an event script: `catalog/controller/event/my_event.php`

```
/* after */
public function modifyCheckoutPageHtml($route, &$args, &$output) {
    /*
        if the view route is 'journal3/checkout/checkout',
        aka: 'catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/journal3/checkout/checkout.twig'
    */
    if ($route == 'journal3/checkout/checkout') {
        /* replace the title with your own title */
        $output = str_replace('<h1 class="title page-title">Quick Checkout</h1>', '<h1 class="title page-title">I have changed this title!</h1>', $output);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

now I am suffering from new problem
I can do some code when user click this button(繼續===continue)in default 6step checkout through

$this->model_setting_event->addEvent('name','catalog/controller/checkout/payment_method/save/after', 'function');

[image]

but in journal3 one step checkout do not have that button.

Comment: If you want to modify the Journal checkout page, the route name should be `catalog/controller/journal3/checkout//* after or before */`. Or you may tell me which view file you want to modify, I can help you to look for the route name.

Comment: I want to run event when user click confirm button. And I found that there is no addOrderHistory function in ** catalog/model/journal3/order ** :(

Comment: I have tried add  addOrderHistory function manually in ** catalog/model/journal3/order.php file **. do not work

Comment: And I tried change private function addOrder to public function in ** catalog/model/journal3/order.php file **. do not work

Comment: oh~this route work ** catalog/model/checkout/order/addOrderHistory/before **

Comment: It depends on when you want to trigger the event, the example I shown was in `controller`, but since your approach was implement at `model` that will works too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).